# PHP: mysqli_sql_exception vs mysql $errno and $error

Tags: php, mysqli

Should I use mysql_sql_exception to get errors in the sql querys or should I use the member variables $errno and $error?

Are they equivalent?

```
try {
    $result = $db->query($query);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    //Error
}

// OR

$result = $db->query($query);
if ($db->errno != 0) {
    //Error
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your mysqli error reporting settings. You can change them using [mysqli_report() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php). For example, if you call `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` - the `mysqli_sql_exception` will be thrown for errors instead of warnings.

Comment: So, what is always safe is to check `$errno`. `mysqli_sql_exception` does not get any further error conditions and can pass some of them depending on the report level set. I am right?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer try-catch and `mysqli_sql_exception` over `$errno`. It is more modern way. Who knows, maybe mysqli functions will not generate errors in some next php version.